# MaterialViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design

Решил посмотреть и поиграться с библиотекой: https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager, но когда запускаю приложение layout отображается на телефоне не так как надо, а в студий также как и в описаний библиотеки. Делаю все как в описаний, но в чем проблема?  [image: Как отображается в телефоне]